# Consumable In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi I'm trying to make an in-app store in my game for players to buy virtual currencies, which is consumables. But I am a bit unsure if my approach is correct or not. So I think it might be good to ask for help here.

After pressing the Buy Button, buyProductIdentifier is called

```
- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

  NSLog(@"Buying %@...", productIdentifier);

  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier: productIdentifier];
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

and then followed up by paymentQueue

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{


  CCLOG(@"PAYMENT QUEUE CALLED!");

  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
  {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
      {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
//      case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
//          [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
      }
  }
}
```

I tried by commenting out the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored case in order to make the player complete a purchase every time instead of popping up a message saying that "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded".

Is this approach correct? if not, can you guys give me some hints?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a code problem.

Are you sure that you you have created the In-App Purchases in iTunes Connect as "Consumable" ?

If you have chosen "Non-Consumable" it is only possible to buy the item once.

Comment: Yes I have set all the In-App Purchases as Consumable. Now it suddenly works after taking a break. Weird! I guess you're right. Thank you!:)